# Summing at each vector entry to the end of the vector

Tags: r

I have

```
X <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

and I want an output of the sum of X as

```
Y <- c(21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6)
```

I read on `rollapply` but it sum only 3 consecutive numbers at a time so can someone help me?

Comment: Yes I tried it and it works but I would want to sum up to a particular nth entry not the entire vector. for instance sum up to 11 not 6 is there a way I can do that? since the rev turns it upside down and I don't want that.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please have a look

Answer (score 4):

You need `cumsum`. Try

```
rev(cumsum(rev(X)))
#[1] 21 20 18 15 11  6
```

If you want to have a set range to sum, you can index, i.e.

```
rev(cumsum(rev(X))[-1])
#[1] 21 20 18 15 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is by using `rcumsum` function from `FSA` package:

```
library(FSA)
X <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
rcumsum(X)

[1] 21 20 18 15 11  6
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** To use rollapply specify the widths as 6:1 (the first element should be the sum of 6 values, the next is the sum of 5 values and so on).

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(X, length(X):1, sum, align = "left")
## [1] 21 20 18 15 11  6
```

**2)** and here is a base solution that does not use rev:

```
X - cumsum(X) + sum(X)
## [1] 21 20 18 15 11  6
```